# In Google Chrome console, how to see where and how tag is modified?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console

I am working on a website based on Prestashop, and there is a  tag which classes are changed (from "col-md-12" to "col-md-6") when one activate a switcher.

I would like to be abble to see how and where this changed is made in the javascript code (I suppose it must be Javascript that make the change).

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Open chrome developer tools (`F12` on Windows/Linux,
   `Command+Option+I` on Mac).
2. Click on the element picker at the top-left corner of the devtools
   panel.

[image]

3. With this tool selected, find (in page) and click on the element whose
   attribute is changed at runtime. The tag must now be highlighted in devtools panel 
   too. Right-click the highlighted tag in devtools.
4. In the pop-up menu, hover over **Break on** and select **attribute
   modification**.
5. Click the switch that changes the class to `col-md-6`.

Please note that this will pause the execution every time one of the attribute is modified, which includes addition/removal of an attribute or change in their values.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but one the execution is paused (because attribute has been changed), how can you know which code is responsible for this change ? thanks

Comment: The debugger should highlight the line when modification to one of the attributes happens.